# Trigger a function one time on mouse scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I am searching for a way to trigger a function exactly one time on mouse scroll. All methods that I found trigger multiple times while scrolling is still in progress.

This is what I came up with. Here the console.log triggers 40-50 times on one scroll. I need something that triggers one time.

```
$(window).bind("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function(event) {
    // Events when scrolled down.
    if (
        event.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0 ||
        event.originalEvent.detail > 0
    ) {
        console.log("Scrolled")
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `one` to bind the event. From the docs at http://api.jquery.com/one/:

> Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed **at most once** per element per event type.

```js
$(window).one("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function(event) {
    console.log("Scrolled")
});
```

```css
#content {
  width: 100px;
  height: 10000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Another note: `bind` should not be used with jQuery anymore, now `on` should be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.one`

```
 $(window).one('scroll',function() {

    });
```

**OR**

```
$(window).on('scroll',function() {
   //do here what you want
   $(window).off('scroll');
});
```